# Javascript not working outside jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, iframe, jsfiddle

Hi I need to load this code to my web inside an iframe. It seems that the javascript code isn´t loading right but I have the same code on jsfiddle and is working right, what I´m missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this scripts were mising:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js">
</script>
```